# WPF Пользовательский шаблон управления

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

[image: LeftMenuItem]

[image: LeftMenu]

Пробую работать с пользовательским шаблонам. Объяснить как сделать "атрибут" у моего элемента, который будет присваивать/возвращать, например Имя.

На картинках видно, что в `LeftMenuItem` у меня есть `Labal`, и я хочу задать для него текст в компонент `LeftMenu` где этот элемент используется. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается так:

1. Заводим себе `UserControl` стандартным способом:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.LeftMenuItem"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <Grid>
           <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum"/>
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```

   ```
   public partial class LeftMenuItem : UserControl
   {
       public LeftMenuItem()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Добавляем в `UserControl` нужное `DependencyProperty` стандартным образом:

   ```
   public string Header
   {
       get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
       set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(LeftMenuItem));
   ```
3. Пользуемся им в XAML'е:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                             AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
   ```
4. Пользуемся им в коде, который включает этот `UserControl`:

   ```
   <local:LeftMenuItem Header="{Binding HeaderText}" .../>
   ```

Всё!

Comment: Пишет "Член "Header" не распознан или недоступен". Как исправить?

Comment: @Boreek: Где пишет? Дайте больше информации и кода (но не весь, конечно).

Comment: <local:LeftMenuItem Header="myTitile"/> - код

Comment: А ошибку выдает при компилирование проекта

Comment: @Boreek: А вы не забыли положить свойство `Header` в `LeftMenuItem`? Покажите его код.

Comment: Все было гораздо проще, у меня просто тупила студия. Не очищала список предупреждений и ошибок

Answer (score -1):

Прочитали бы документацию МС по этому вопросу - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms751709(v=vs.110).aspx

Либо, если хотите комплексно изучать, то посмотрите видеоуроки - http://itvdn.com/ru/video/wpf

Comment: Каким образом документация на Alignment и Padding помогает в данном вопросе?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?